# Writing an XPath query for Google importXML function

Tags: xml, xpath, import, google-sheets

I'm trying to find the xpath query for use in google spreadsheets (importXML function) to obtain the following information contained in the HTML code below: "ThisIsCompanyName" & "123456".

```
<tr valign="top" class="small"> 
                                <th width="18%" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" id="name" class="commonFontSize"> 
                                  <div align="right">Company Name</div></th>
                                <td width="33%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" headers="name" align="left" style="padding-left:3px;"> 
                                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTblCarrierName" class="oneSmallFontSize">ThisIsCompanyName</span>    
                                </td>
                                <th width="20%" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" id="dot" class="commonFontSize"> 
                                  <div align="right">U.S. DOT Number</div></th>
                                <td width="29%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" headers="dot" align="left" style="padding-left:3px;"> 
                                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTblDOTNumber" class="oneSmallFontSize">123456</span>  
                                </td>
                              </tr>
```

Using Chrome, if I use the "inspect element" function and then "copy xpath" I get the following....

```
    //*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTblCarrierName"]
    //*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTblDOTNumber"]
```

But these are not yielding the results i need.  I have zero knowledge of programming and am just trying to learn some rudimentary web scraping techniques.

Comment: If it helps here's the website I'm trying to get this information from...   http://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/PassengerSearch/carrier_detail.aspx?DOT=oX6079bScNU=&DOCKET=Yyy+dvgHb30=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
//span[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTblCarrierName']/text()
//span[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTblDOTNumber']/text()
```

And if you use this xpath, it will return "ThisIsCompanyName123456"

```
//span[@class='oneSmallFontSize']/text()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working....I'm getting this error message on google spreadsheet: "error: The xPath query given could not be evaluated. Please check the syntax of the query: //span[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTblCarrierName']/text()"

Comment: It seems to be working for me, what are you using to evaluate? Using the chrome built in console I'm able to evaluate the xpath by using $x("//span[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTblCarrierName']/text()")

Comment: It ended up only working when i used  //td[@headers="_____"], but sure why, just a lot of trial and error.  thanks :)